# what is meaning of this quote by Lahiri Mahasaya?

Tags: quote

what is meaning of this quote ?

> If you don’t invite God to be your summer Guest, He won’t come in the winter of your life - Lahiri Mahasaya

I found this quote on [Pinakin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3872/pinakin) profile

Comment: Summer - sunny days or happy times (when we need god least). Winter - gloomy or sad times (when we need god most).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that spiritual effort must start early in life. It would not be possible to make spiritual progress in one's old age.

**Spiritual effort needs to start early**

> As long as the body is healthy, free from sickness, as long as old age
> has not set in, as long as the power of sense-organs is not impaired,
> as long as there is no risk to life, an intelligent man should
> endeavor for the welfare of the soul. **It is foolishness to dig a well
> when the house has caught fire.**

**[Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, chapter XIII]**